# Jquery is not Working - Not detaching first element of li and attaching back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've have this code.

```
var setOfCars = jQuery(".mainList li.cars");
```

Here.. setOfCars var contains two LIs ( two sets of LI ).

I just want to detach first Li and attach it back to specified index location like this :-

```
var firstFeaturedCar = jQuery(setOfCars)[0];
jQuery(".mainListSecond li").eq((index)*2).after(firstFeaturedCar);
```

Somehow, it's not working. Please Help. Thanks. :)

Comment: You need to elaborate on "not working", provide a clear problem statement with a minimal example of code to demonstrate the fault.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to detach first LI from setOfCars variable to attach it back to specified index location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var firstli= $('.mainListSecond li').first()
$('.mainListSecond li').eq(1).after(firstli);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6qg0juc/)**

Answer (score 1):

Give this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

To move the 1 below the 2:

`$("ul li:first").insertAfter($("ul li:last"))`

Or given this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Move the 2nd `li` into the number 4 spot:

`$("ul li:nth-child(2)").insertAfter($("ul li:nth-child(4)"))`

Wrapping it up into a function:

```
function moveListItemTo(list, from, to) {
    list.find("li:nth-child(" + from + ")").insertAfter(items.find("li:nth-child(" + to + ")"))
}
```

Usage:

`moveListItemTo($("ul"), 2, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jQuery(setOfCars+":nth-child(2)");
```

instead of:

```
jQuery(setOfCars)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using this a bunch with different indexes, you might consider making a function like:

```js
function shiftCar(selector, curIndex, newIndex ){
   $(selector).eq(curIndex).remove().insertAfter($(selector).eq(newIndex-1));
}
shiftCar(".mainList li.cars",0,2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainList">
  <li class="cars">First</li>
  <li class="cars">Second</li>
  <li class="cars">Third</li>
</ul>
```